# i can't add files to my repository subversion, it throws an internal error (code 500)

Tags: apache, svn, tortoisesvn, windows-server-2012

Hello all and thanks in advance,

I hope somebody can help me, because i have a problem with subversion when i try to add files to my repository, it throws an internal error (code 500).

My machine runs a Windows server 2012, i have installed XAMPP 1.8.3, SVN 1.8.10, The dir "D:/server/svn/ " have all the required permissions for all the users and I have the firewall disabled
Here is my setup:

httpd.conf

```
 Addons config
Include conf/addons/*.conf
```

conf/addons/svn.conf

```
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so

LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so
LoadModule dontdothat_module modules/mod_dontdothat.so

#<location "/svn">
#   DAV svn
#   SVNParentPath D:/server/svn
#   SVNListParentPath On
#</location>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAlias svn.yeisoft.tk
     ServerName svn.yeisoft.tk
     <Location "/">
         DAV svn
        #SVNPath D:/server/svn/
    SVNParentPath D:/server/svn/
        SVNListParentPath On
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion repository"
    AuthUserFile D:/server/a.htpasswd
    #Order deny,allow
 Satisfy Any
    Require valid-user
    AuthzSVNAccessFile  D:/server/svn-authz.conf
     </Location>

 </VirtualHost>
```

a.htpasswd

```
user:pass
```

svn-auth.conf

```
[groups]
administrator = Enrique

[/]
@administrator = rw
```

Here a list of what I have done to get this error:
- Created a new repository with svnadmin (Success)
- Added files to the new repository (Success)
- Update existing files (Success)
- Add some new files (error 500)

Below you can see the logs from the file access.log and error.log :

access.log

```
85.214.204.52 - - [27/Oct/2014:21:13:08 +0100] "OPTIONS /pruebasanaarte/application/controllers HTTP/1.1" 401 - "-" "SVN/1.8.10 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.7 TortoiseSVN-1.8.8.25755"
85.214.204.52 - Enrique [27/Oct/2014:21:13:08 +0100] "OPTIONS /pruebasanaarte/application/controllers HTTP/1.1" 200 194 "-" "SVN/1.8.10 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.7 TortoiseSVN-1.8.8.25755"
85.214.204.52 - Enrique [27/Oct/2014:21:13:08 +0100] "OPTIONS /pruebasanaarte/application/controllers HTTP/1.1" 200 97 "-" "SVN/1.8.10 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.7 TortoiseSVN-1.8.8.25755"
85.214.204.52 - Enrique [27/Oct/2014:21:13:08 +0100] "POST /pruebasanaarte/!svn/me HTTP/1.1" 201 - "-" "SVN/1.8.10 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.7 TortoiseSVN-1.8.8.25755"
85.214.204.52 - Enrique [27/Oct/2014:21:13:08 +0100] "HEAD /pruebasanaarte/application/controllers/a.txt HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "SVN/1.8.10 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.7 TortoiseSVN-1.8.8.25755"
85.214.204.52 - Enrique [27/Oct/2014:21:13:08 +0100] "DELETE /pruebasanaarte/!svn/txn/1-6 HTTP/1.1" 204 - "-" "SVN/1.8.10 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.7 TortoiseSVN-1.8.8.25755"
```

error.log

```
[Mon Oct 27 21:20:16.586206 2014] [:error] [pid 1152:tid 1792] (20014)Internal error: [client 85.214.204.52:53703] Can't open file 'D:\\server\\svn\\error\\format': El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.  
[Mon Oct 27 21:20:16.586206 2014] [dav:error] [pid 1152:tid 1792] [client 85.214.204.52:53703] Could not fetch resource information.  [500, #0]
[Mon Oct 27 21:20:16.586206 2014] [dav:error] [pid 1152:tid 1792] [client 85.214.204.52:53703] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #720003]
[Mon Oct 27 21:20:16.586206 2014] [dav:error] [pid 1152:tid 1792] [client 85.214.204.52:53703] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #720003]
```

I don't know what's happening here, but I would be grateful if somebody throw me some light about this.

Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: The question is offtopic on StackOverflow, BTW. Ask such questions on ServerFault next time.

Comment: ok , didn't know. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround to avoid the error 500. It's not a real solution i think, but it let me work well without any problem.

I have given the svn what it wants, a repository called "error" and now I'm able to work with other ones.

I will mark this as an answer, but thanks for all that have helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Your Apache HTTP Server [is configured with `SVNParentPath D:/server/svn/` directive](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/mod_dav_svn/conf/). It means that `D:\server\svn\` is the parent directory for multiple repositories. According to your httpd.conf file, the URL `http://svn.yeisoft.tk/` leads to the collection of your repositories, however there are no repositories in `D:\server\svn\` at all, I guess.

The error that you get is:

> [Mon Oct 27 21:20:16.586206 2014] [:error] [pid 1152:tid 1792]
>   (20014)Internal error: [client 85.214.204.52:53703] Can't open file
>   'D:\server\svn\error\format': El sistema no puede encontrar la
>   ruta especificada.

So you've attempted to access a repository "D:\server\svn\error" which most likely does not exist at all. `format` file which is missing must exist in a repository on a filesystem.

- Make sure that your Location and svn-related directives were configured properly.
- Otherwise, install VisualSVN Server on your Windows Server 2012 machine. Using VisualSVN Server instead of a self-built Subversion+Apache server will keep you out of server configuration and administration headache.